# Select com subquery

Tags: mysql, select, sql-select

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT id_usuario,
SUM(CASE p.tp_honorario WHEN 'Mensal' THEN (h.vl_honorario * 12) ELSE h.vl_honorario END) as valor
FROM empresa_honorario as h 
INNER JOIN honorario as p ON p.id_honorario = h.id_honorario 
WHERE h.id_empresa = 86 OR p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal'
GROUP BY h.id_usuario
```

Que me retorna:

```
id_usuario  valor
1           3000
2           2400
```

Quando coloco esse select como subquery, pegando só o `valor`, e filtrando por cada usuário:

```
SELECT SUM(e.vl_imposto) as imposto, SUM(e.vl_total) as vl_total, u.nm_usuario,

(SELECT SUM(CASE p.tp_honorario WHEN 'Mensal' THEN (h.vl_honorario * 12) ELSE h.vl_honorario END) as valor
FROM empresa_honorario as h 
INNER JOIN honorario as p ON p.id_honorario = h.id_honorario 
WHERE h.id_usuario = e.id_usuario AND h.id_empresa = 86 OR p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal'
GROUP BY h.id_usuario)

FROM impostos as e 
INNER JOIN usuario as u ON e.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
WHERE e.id_empresa = 86 GROUP BY e.id_usuario
```

Dá o erro:

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Como fazer para essa subquery considerar só um usuário de cada vez?

Comment: Tente no final da subquery limitar a uma row: `...GROUP BY h.id_usuario LIMIT 1`

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu de agrupa o campo (  u.nm_usuario,  ) bem no final `WHERE e.id_empresa = 86 GROUP BY e.id_usuario , u.nm_usuario`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este erro ocorre pois sua consulta retorna mais de um resultado, o que não é possível já que você quer coloca-lo em uma coluna da sua consulta principal, o que você pode fazer é colocar um `limit` para retornar apenas um resultado:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE p.tp_honorario WHEN 'Mensal' THEN (h.vl_honorario * 12) ELSE    h.vl_honorario END) as valor
FROM empresa_honorario as h 
INNER JOIN honorario as p ON p.id_honorario = h.id_honorario 
WHERE h.id_usuario = e.id_usuario AND h.id_empresa = 86 OR p.tp_honorario = 'Mensal'
GROUP BY h.id_usuario
LIMIT 1
```

---

**Ou colocar outras condições no seu `WHERE`, garantindo que seja retornado apenas um registro.**